# How to update CSS to values that were chosen in a form? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the idea I would like to develop. I need to have an element, lets say a button. And next to it I would have various inputs that will allow user to edit button. Once user changes something I need to update preview of the button and css code of it. At the moment I am  quiet confused and don't understand how to do it. 
I found this website: http://css3button.net/ 
It shows exactly what I need. I tried looking at source, but didn't understand it quiet well. So basically I need a jQuery Solution to achieve same functionality as in example website (allow user to change style options, update css and preview instantly after user changes values.)

Ideally could you provide an example with your answer please, maybe simple form to change color and border of the div tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do neraly all of those with only one function [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/). Also `.attr()`, .`val()`, `.addClass()/removeClass()` may usefull.

Look here for [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/safarov/9tPF8/)

Look for [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/safarov/q2ZYA/)

Comment: The prob is that I'm not really good with jQuery. I took a quick read of provided link. Could you please provide small jsFiddle example, with all bits (update code, preview and fields) I find it easier to understand something when I see examples. Sorry if i'm asking a lot.

Comment: Yeh, but the thing with a demo is that it only changes color to yellow, I need to have an input where user enters hex color and than jQuery updates it to that color.

Comment: @IlyaKnaup Check for demo 2 but, this the last. You must learn jquery if you want to write applications like this

Comment: Thank You! Exactly what I needed, I'll figure other parts now, Sorry for so many questions.

Answer (score 2):

this would change all divs with the class `mydiv` :

```
$(.mydiv).css('background-color', 'red');
```

same syntax is applicable to border, color, or other `CSS` styles

this function uses 2 inputboxes to set specified background color for the elements with the specified class

```
function changeBgColor() 

{
     var mycolor = document.getElementById('myinputboxcolor').value;
     var myclass = document.getElementById('myinputboxclass').value;
     $('.' + myclass).css('background-color', mycolor);
}
```

Comment: Ok got this part, but instead of 'red' in your example, how would I put value from input there? e.g. user chooses #f0f0f0 color and types it in input class=test , how would I launch your function but with color chosen by user?

Comment: u would just need a function which reads a value from a specific textbox and assign it to a variable which u later insert into the .css command , i will edit my answer and add a small function